# How do you process all files in a folder?

Tags: python, pandas, directory-structure, listdir

I want to run my code on all files in a directory. The code works fine on a single file, but my attempts to iterate on multiple files tells me

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.xlsx'

```
directory = r"C:/Users/name/Desktop/folder/2018"
arrivals_aggregated = pd.DataFrame()

print(os.listdir(directory))
for filename in os.listdir(smt_directory):

    print('current file is ' + filename)
    x = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    symbols = x_symbols(x)
    arv = x.parse(sheet_name='Arrivals', skiprows=5, usecols=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])
    arrivals = x_arrivals(arv, x)

arrivals_aggregated.append(arrivals)
```

I expect it to iterate across all the files in the directory, processing and aggregating the results to a big dataframe arrivals_aggregated. Instead it is stopping at x = pd.ExcelFile(filename), saying that file not found, even though it is there and even prints when I include

print('current file is ' + filename)

It is failing on the very first file in the folder without ever processing the code.

Comment: Side-note: In modern Python, the simplest fix here is to replace `for filename in os.listdir(...):` with `for entry in os.scandir(...):`, and change uses of `filename` (where you want the full path) to `entry.path` or (where you want the name without the path) to `entry.name`. `scandir` is faster than `listdir`, and also gives you free (or at least, cached) access to `stat` related info on the file (e.g. is it actually a file or a directory, what is the size, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking to make the adjustment you are suggesting here, as I may be interested in the stats and might incorporate this into the code for some selection.  How are you exactly suggesting that I would update the code? for entry in os.scandir(...): and then replace filename with entry.path?

Comment: Yup. Saves the need for `os.path.join` entirely; the qualified path is available directly without additional work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this works depends on where you run the script. If `filename` is not present in the directory where you ran your script, then you will get a `FileNotFoundError`.

I would instead do:

```
x = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.sep.join([directory, filename]))
```

which will ensure you're passing the true file location to `pd.ExcelFile`.

Comment: Don't use `.sep`; there is already a directory joining function in the module that takes the arguments positionally (and handles some edge cases plain string join does not), so `os.path.sep.join([directory, filename])` simplifies to `os.path.join(directory, filename)` (`.sep` removed and `[]` removed).

Comment: totally worked, thank you.